# android ImageView allways top and bottom

Tags: android, android-imageview

In activity, i has 2 ImageView and LinearLayout1 hold some text and button.
i want like :

[image]

how to do it?

Comment: Do a relativelayout.

Comment: @Razgriz : all of it in RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` attribute place the imageview on top.It works when parent is Relative Layout
  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` attribute place the imageview on bottom.It works when parent is Relative Layout

Answer (score 0):

1.Try this RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/black"></LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Try this LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```